# Unable to do search after uploading new package

Tags: maven, archiva

The problem currently is that when I upload a new package to [Archiva](https://archiva.apache.org/), In the browse tab, I can see my package, i.e.,
[image]

While in the Search tab, when I try to do the searching (using admin account), no result returned, i.e.,
[image]

I have tried to reindex the repository but nothing helps, i.e.,
[image]

Also I can download this package through maven in Eclipse. The only problem is the searching function. May I ask if there are other setting related to the searching function?